# Can someone find out $x$ in the figure?

Tags: geometry

[image]

Can someone find $x$ in the figure?
I tried to solve it, but failed.

Comment: what did you got ? 20?

Comment: @Steven31415 I didn't get any value. Even, now I am wondering if it can be solved.

Comment: @Danny_Kim the position of all the vertices is uniquely determined by the given angles, so there is a unique solution, so it **can** be solved. It seems however that the solution is not so easy to find by finding triangles whose angles sum to 180...

Comment: It's at the top of the upper left triangle.

Comment: reminds me of this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUTW9.jpg